# Trying to configure VPN client using l2tp on Ubuntu 18.04 to connect to Cisco meraki security device

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, meraki

I am trying to configure VPN client on ubuntu18.04 that will connect to VPN service on Cisco Meraki security device using l2tp over IPSec but I am getting error in the logs on both ends.

[Errors in ubuntu logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfFSc.png)

[Meraki errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2zmj.png)

Please suggest a solution

Answer (score 0):

Follow the following steps:
i) Install L2TP Plugins for Network Manager as, by default, support for L2TP VPNs is not installed for Network Manager, so we need to install them

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install network-manager-l2tp

sudo apt-get install network-manager-l2tp-gnome

ii) Now, disable System xl2tpd using below commands:

```
sudo systemctl stop xl2tpd
sudo systemctl disable xl2tpd
```

iii) Goto Settings-> Network

iv) Click on '+' icon under 'VPN' to Add a VPN

v) Add VPN Dialog box will appear. Select 'Layer 2 Tunneling Protocol (L2TP).
[View Image of Select L2TP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2yGG.png)

vi)   Next it will ask to enter the following things.
[View Image to Add VPN Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5guUh.png)
               i) Name: VPN Connection Name as per your choice.
               ii) In General Gateway: Enter the VPN gatewayid  for e.g. abc@cloudpursuit.com as provided by Cisco Meraki Client VPN
               iii) Under Authentication, 
                            Userid:  provided by Cisco Meraki Client VPN
                            Password: provided by Cisco Meraki Client VPN
vii) View the image as below:
[Image filled with details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqpJu.png)
viii) Click on IPsec Settings. Check the checkbox of "Enable IPsec tunnel to L2TP host". 
ix) Enter the pre-shared key 
   Phase1 algorithms as: 3des-sha1-modp1024
   Phase2 algorithms as: 3des-sha1
   Click 'OK'
[view image for preshared keys](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tanU8.png)

x) Now click on 'PPP Settings' button. L2TP PPP Options dialog will open. Check the checkbox against 'PAP' whereas uncheck the rest of options as follows:
[view PPP settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkxKh.png)

xi) In security and compression keep all the check boxes selected as follows:
[View Security and compression settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7GlQ.png)

xii) Click on "Ok" buton and then Click on "Apply" button on top right of the "AddVPN" dialog box to add and save the VPN settings.

Xiii) Now the VPN will be added and will be displayed in the list of VPNs.
Click on "ON" Toggle button to Connect the VPN. 
[Image of VPN toggle button kept on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzTRo.png)

Xiv) You will find the VPN icon on top right side of the screen as connected, before volume bar in the image 
[View image of VPN as connected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4lju.jpg)